# Как в отладчике в Eclipse посмотреть, откуда был вызван данный метод?

Tags: java, отладка, eclipse

Можно как-нибудь в отладчике в Eclipse посмотреть, откуда был вызван данный метод?
То есть поставили break point на строке внутри какого-то метода, выполнение на этом месте приостановилось, и надо узнать, откуда данный метод был только что вызван.

Comment: @dmitry_iii Добавлена метка java, если Вы используете Eclipse для работы с другим языком, пожалуйста, уточните.

Answer (score 2):

В режиме отладки вкладка Debug содержит call stack

Answer (score 0):

контрл+шифт+П - находит все места в программе, где вызывался искомый метод